# Looking for a Book

Tags: options, greeks

I hope everyone is well. While I was looking for derivations of Greeks I came across part of a book. Could you help me to find its name please ?

Here is the link: http://centerforpbbefr.rutgers.edu/TaipeiPBFR%26D/01-16-09%20papers/5-4%20Greek%20letters.doc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That seems to be chapter 30 of

> [A Handbook of Quantitative Finance and Risk Management](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-0-387-77117-5)
>
> 2010, Cheng-Few Lee, Alice C. Lee, John Lee
>
> ISBN: 9780387771175 (online) or  9780387771168 (print)

Comment: Wow, is this price real??

Comment: Wow, didn't even notice that - pretty insane. Looks like Amazon is consistent, though: https://www.amazon.com/Handbook-Quantitative-Finance-Risk-Management/dp/0387771166.

Comment: Yeah I also double-checked with AMZN as I couldn't believe it either...